# Unable to deploy SWT WebStart app on windows 64 bit

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, swt, java-web-start

I have a Java WebStart (javaws) application written using Eclipse. I have exported and signed all the jars, written the .jnlp file and so on.

Here is the abbreviated jnlp file with some OS resources removed for the sake of brevity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.5+"
    codebase="http://www.foobarx.com/"
    href="fhr.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Foo Bar</title>
        <vendor>foobarx.com</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.foobarx.com" />
        <description>Java App</description>
        <icon href="daffodils.jpg" kind="splash"/>
    </information>

    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>

    <resources>
        <jar href="fhr.jar" />
    </resources>

    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
        <jar href="swt-4.2.2-win32-win32-x86_64.jar" />
    </resources>

    <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
        <nativelib href="swt-4.2.2-win32-win32-x86.jar" />
    </resources>

    <resources os="Linux" arch="amd64">
        <nativelib href="swt-4.2-gtk-linux-x86_64.jar" />
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="com.foobarx.client.FBXApplication" />
</jnlp>
```

I can load the app from my browser in Linux, or in Windows XP 32 bit and it runs flawlessly. But when I try to load the app from Windows 7 64 bit I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/events/DisposeListener
```

There is a 32 bit JVM running on the 64 bit Windows 7 machine, because the browser is 32 bit and apparently this is how it is done.

When I run it on Win7/64 Java does not find the SWT methods, although it does load the correct SWT library file, which I have verified.

The manifest file was generated by Eclipse, and it is basically empty. I tried adding the current working directory in the class path by typing a dot, but this did not change anything.

So to sum it up, I have a Java Webstart app hosted on a remote server. I can launch it from a browser in Linux or Windows XP 32 bit. If I attempt to launch it from Windows 7 Pro 64 bit from Firefox or IE with a 32 bit JVM, I get a NoClassDefFound error. The class in question is a class from the SWT libraries.

Questions:

Has anyone had this specific type of deployment problem, or an idea as to where to look next?

Any/all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this problem arise from an incorrect/incomplete manifest file?

I think it is instead caused by having the SWT jars mentioned in the manifest at all.  Anything mentioned in the Class-Path of the manifest will be provided to every application, regardless of 32/64 bit.

Being provided with 2 jars is confusing the class loader, which will probably attempt to load the method from the 1st Jar on the class-path that contains it.

Instead reference the SWT Jars in `resource` sections in the JNLP that are delineated by architecture.  That way, each architecture will be provided with only the jars it actually needs (they will be added to the run-time class-path).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity here. The result is the same with or without the class-path information in the manifest. The correct swt libraries are described in the jnlp file which has been validated. Here is a snippet: `<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
  <nativelib href="swt-4.2.2-win32-win32-x86.jar" />
 </resources>`

Comment: *"..with or without the class-path information in the manifest."*  Was the app. completely uninstalled between tests?

Comment: Yes. I re-exported the main jar file, and resigned all of the jar files including the swt libraries. Then I uploaded them, overwriting the previous jar files. I have revised the post to make it a little clearer. I understand your point about the manifest file so it would not make sense to put platform-specific file references in the manifest. What puzzles me is that the correct SWT file is being downloaded by JWS but then it is not finding the classes in that file. Thanks for your input.

Comment: None of what you described says to me 'yes the app. was uninstalled between tests'.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "uninstalled". I could delete the old jar files before I upload the new ones, but that would be the same as overwriting them. How do I uninstall a javaws app?

Comment: *"I am not sure what you mean by "uninstalled"."*  So ask.  Is that so difficult a concept to understand?  *"How do I uninstall a javaws app?"*  1) Open the [Java Cache Viewer](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp) 2) Select the app. 3) Click the big red X. -- those instructions are for the Oracle JRE, BTW.

Comment: I cleared the cache, then ran the app with Eclipse's manifest file. I then cleared the cache again and ran it with my own manifest file. Only difference was a dot in the class-path. The result was the same: NoClassDefFound error.

Comment: Solved. It was in the jnlp file. I had to create two resources, one called "nativelib" and another called "jar" and they both reference the swt file. Thanks for your input. I learnt stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The jnlp file stores OS-specific resource information in a resource tag like so:

```
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="swt-4.2.2-win32-win32-x86_64.jar" />
</resources>
```

The os and arch properties together tell javaws which files contain the resources specific to its platform. In my original jnlp file the href to the os-specfic resources was in a tag called "nativelib". This worked on all platforms except Windows 64 bit. When I changed the name of the tag to "jar" instead of "nativelib" it worked on Win64. I am not yet certain what is the correct approach. I may use both "nativelib" and "jar" for all platforms just to be safe.